# Scalacl compiling error

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalacl

I am attempting to use scalacl. I have added scalacl as an Xplugin for my project, but when I do it gives me two errors:

1) Error in Scala compiler: null
2) SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'null'. Check Error Log for details.

It also gives this error in a pop-up window:
An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
Scala compiler cannot initialize for project: HelloWorld. Please check that your classpath contains the standard Scala library.

Comment: So scala is really on classpath?

Comment: I can compile and run scala code without the scalacl library. I'm not very informed when it comes to java stuff. Am I using the wrong scala library?